# Meld not launching in Ubuntu

Tags: python, meld

I just installed `meld` in Ubuntu 20.04. Upon trying to launch `meld`, I got the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/meld", line 79, in <module>
    import meld.conf  # noqa: E402
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'meld.conf'
```

After this, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50783742/can-not-start-meld-on-ubuntu-16-04-as-error-import-meld-conf) solution where the answer suggests changing `#!/usr/bin/python` to `#!/usr/bin/python2`. Upon changing, I got the following error message:

```
  File "/usr/bin/meld", line 243
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file /usr/bin/meld on line 243, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

The solution for this being given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639275/python-syntaxerror-non-ascii-character-xe2-in-file) about the missing line `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`. Now after this, I am back to original error:

```
  File "/usr/bin/meld", line 81, in <module>
    import meld.conf  # noqa: E402
ImportError: No module named meld.conf
```

The only thing I have done is making `python3` as the default `python` prior to this.

Comment: How did you install meld? I'm using the distribution-provided version with python3 (the default), and it works perfectly well...

Comment: By regular `sudo`? `sudo apt install meld`

Comment: How strange. I can't reproduce your problems, although I'm using exactly the same system.

Comment: Can you check that meld's source files, including `conf.py`, are present in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/meld/`?

Comment: To reproduce follow build steps in ubuntu from https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/meld. meld ends up installed in /usr/local/bin. I do not have installed any other way.

Answer (score 1):

Having similar problem with Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.
After some debugging, I realized that I also had meld installed via:
pip install meld

resulted with undesired /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/meld folder.

My solution was running (as root):

```
# pip uninstall meld
```

now /usr/bin/meld
as was installed via:
 apt install meld 
works fine.

Comment: Which was a library https://pypi.org/project/meld/

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with Ubuntu 22.04. Finally figured out that I had both a /usr/local/lib/python3 and a /usr/local/lib/python3.10. The "python3" had a dist-packages/meld dir and the 3.10 version didn't; in fact, the 3.10 version had nothing in it. So I moved the python3.10 dir to python3.10.save and then did "sudo ln -s python3 python3.10" and after that all was good. I had built from source (I wanted the latest version and why it was in /usr/local), so I'll guess there is an error in the build files for meld.